# Start Metro App without Explorer.exe running

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, kiosk, windows-10

I am developing a Kiosk Terminal application for Windows 8/8.1/10. I am encountering a problem that I cannot launch any metro apps with explorer.exe turned off. For instance:

Windows 10 (Preview Build : 10130)
 I tried launching bingnews with the command "Start bingnews://" in command prompt.It is giving me the following exception: "The wait Operation timed out"

Windows 8/8.1:
Here on doing the same procedure, as above, I got the exception - "The app manager is required to activate applications, but is not running"

Comment: why do you have the requirement to have explorer disabled? Win81 (Pro/Enterprise) have a Kiosk Mode (AssignedAccess) where you can select your app to be the only running app.

Comment: I am developing a Custom Kiosk application which has several features not provided by Windows. Just to clarify - By Kiosk Mode of Windows you mean the Metro Interface provided by Windows 8/8.1 right?

Comment: no, KioskMode means, that you can only run 1 Modern Store app: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/assigned-access

Comment: Ok, this is my situation, I have developed a C#.net application using WPF which serves as a Kiosk terminal. It has to run in full screen and should not allow the user to access explorer features in anyways. So, this application is pretty much a shell replacement for windows. Since, explorer.exe is turned off my application is not able to launch any Metro Apps.

Comment: Since Win8.1 you don't need this any longer. Develop it as a normal App and use the AssignedAccess.

Comment: Thanks, I will launch my application with Assigned Access

Comment: I have similar requirement, but I am running Windows 10 Home edition, which does not support Assigned Access feature. So, I too am looking for a way to Activate Windows Store app without explorer.exe running.

Is it possible?